# To form Json from nested POJOS

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have nested POJO as below. All the POJO's are in the same package. Please see student is is the name pojo and all other POJO are inside

```
 class Student{

     String firstName;
     String lastName;

     List <Activities> activites;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<Activities> getActivites() {
        return activites;
    }

    public void setActivites(List<Activities> activites) {
        this.activites = activites;
    }

    }

    class Activites{

    List<Quipments> quipments;

    String time;

    public List<Quipments> getQuipments() {
        return quipments;
    }

    public void setQuipments(List<Quipments> quipments) {
        this.quipments = quipments;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }



    }

    class Quipments{

    String Type;

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }

    }
```

I want to convert the above student POJO in json that will have all the values of other pojo.

We are not suppose to use below api. I know the below one works.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONMarshaller;
```

Want to use something like below

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
```

Please advice

Comment: For required library, see the [link](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: json-simple seems too simple :-) I think you'll have a lot of work reinventing the wheel using it. Why don't you try flexjson, gson or jackson instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use this very popular library https://github.com/google/gson:

```
String sample = "{firstName: \"mardar\", lastName: \"pandit\"}";
com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
Student student = gson.fromJson(sample, Student.class);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(student));
```